# Limit generic case class parameters with upper bound in scala

Tags: scala

I would like to limit parameter function to have parameter only case class with limited field types. Let's say i would allow only `Int` and `String`

```scala
def apply[T <: ???](t: T) {
   ...
}

case class OneParam(int: Int)
case class TwoParams(int: Int, str: String)
case class CompilationErrorClass(list: Array[String])

val oneParam = OneParam(1)
val twoParams = TwoParams(1, "2")
val compilationErrorClass = CompilationErrorClass(List())

val result1 = apply[OneParam](oneParam)
val result2 = apply[TwoParams](twoParams)
val result3 = apply[CompilationErrorClass](compilationErrorClass) // -- this will not compile as has not allowed upper-bound parameter type
```

How this trick can be done in scala?

Comment: Here `T` would refer to the type of the case class with no reference to the types of the case class fields. You would probably need to look into macros to solve this.

Comment: Even if you could do this, what is `apply` actually going to do? How is it going to access the fields of `t` in a type safe way?

Comment: @Tim the idea behind the scene is to write library which will accept case classes with this `apply` method. But i want to limit user application as library will work with limited number of types ( dictionaries will map to those case classes ).
To be more concrete internally it will be new instance created `def apply[T <: ???] = fromJson[T]`
of couse, i can check fields in runtime and throw exception, but it may be more elegant to restrict it during compilation

Comment: This sounds like a good use case for a case class and maybe automatic derivation.

Answer (score 1):

Here we go (scala3):

```
import scala.deriving.Mirror.ProductOf

type AllowTypes = Int *: EmptyTuple | String *: EmptyTuple | (Int, String) | (String, Int)

def size[P <: Product](t: P)
                (using p: ProductOf[P],
              ev: p.MirroredElemTypes <:< AllowTypes): Int =
  Tuple.fromProductTyped(t).size


scala> size(OneParam(0))
val res0: Int = 1

scala> size(TwoParams(1, ""))
val res1: Int = 2

scala> size(CompilationErrorClass(Array()))
-- Error: --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1 |size(CompilationErrorClass(Array()))
  |                                    ^
  |                                    Cannot prove that p.MirroredElemTypes <:< AllowTypes.
1 error found
```

Or even general solution, allow all case classes with arbitrarily  int or string arguments:

```
scala> type Allowed[T <: Tuple] = T match
     |   case EmptyTuple          => DummyImplicit
     |   case (Int | String) *: t => Allowed[t]
     |

scala> import scala.deriving.Mirror.ProductOf
     |
     | def size[P <: Product](t: P)
     |                 (using p: ProductOf[P],
     |                       ev: Allowed[p.MirroredElemTypes]): Int =
     |   Tuple.fromProductTyped(t).size
     |
def size[P <: Product](t: P)(using p: deriving.Mirror.ProductOf[P], ev: Allowed[p.MirroredElemTypes]): Int

scala> case class A(i: Int, j: Int, x: String, y: String)
// defined case class A

scala> case class X(x1: Int, x2: String, x3: Int, x4: String, x5: String)
// defined case class X

scala> case class Y(l: Long)
// defined case class Y

scala> size(A(0, 1, "", ""))
val res0: Int = 4

scala> size(X(0, "", 1, "", ""))
val res1: Int = 5

scala> size(Y(0))
-- Error: --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1 |size(Y(0))
  |    ^
  |    Match type reduction failed since selector  Long *: EmptyTuple.type
  |    matches none of the cases
  |
  |        case EmptyTuple => DummyImplicit
  |        case (Int | String) *: t => Allowed[t]
1 error found
```

Comment: Thanks. This is exact I wanted. I believe in scala2 it should be something similar with runtime mirroring.

Comment: @AlexanderNekrasov Yes, you can use https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless in scala2 to do this.